# How to get point in line which distance n from another point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I have y = kx + b line, and (x1, y1) point and n distance. I want find (x2, y2) point in line which distance from (x1, y1) equals n.[image: Img]

Comment: Do you know an equation relating $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Joe no I don't have, i have only (x1, y1), y = kx and n

Comment: Given a line l and point p, to find the points on l that are distance d from p, construct the circle with center p and radius d.  Depending on the distance from p to l, that circle with either a) not intersect the line, b) be tangent to the line or, c) intersect the line in two points.  If you intend that p lie ON l then there will always be two points.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With point $(x_1, y_1)$, the circle with center $(x_1, y_1)$ and radius n is $(x- x_1)^2+ (y- y_1)^2= n^2$.

That circle intersects line y= kx+ b where $(x- x_1)^2+ (kx+ b- y_1)^2= n^2$.

Multiplying that out, $x^2- 2x_1x+ x_1^2+ k^2x^2+ 2(b- y_1)x+ (b- y_1)^2= n^2$.

We can rewrite that as $(k^2+ 1)x^2+ (2(b- y_1)- 2)x+ (b- y_2)^2+ x_1^2- n^2= 0$ and solve for x using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

On your line, given a difference of *n* between the two points, you can find the desired second point by creating a right triangle with the line as its hypotenuse. One leg would have the length $x2-x1$, and the other would have the length y2-y1. Because it is a right triangle, ${A^2}+{B^2}={C^2}$. Therefore, ${(x2-x1)^2}+{(y2-y1)^2}={n^2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).